# Interpolation as prediction in Python

Tags: python

I have a LOWESS model fitted to my data using statsmodels and I now I want to use that for inference on my test data. The statsmodels packages doesn't provide an interface for inference, but as I have ~14.000 points describing a quite simple relationship, I am sure that linear interpolation will do just fine.

How can extend my code below to use the existing (x,y)-pairs for inference on new observations using linear interpolation?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(100) * 0.2
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac=0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy `interp` on your data like this:

```
import numpy as np
new_x_values = [0,1,2]
np.interp(new_x_values, lowess[:,0], lowess[:,1])
```